# Lazy loading of children

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to React, so I hope my question isn't too dump...

I'm developing a collapsible ui component which toggles the body from open to close on click on a button. This works fine, I'm just curious about one thing.

This component can have a lot of data/components in. Think of a list of 100 or more collapsible components and each component can have another 100 child component.

So I want only to add the children of components who are expanded/open.

So I thought I'm adding a state like "hasBeenOpened" in default to false. The first time it get opened, hasBeenOpened will be set to true, the children be loaded and the height calculated.

The problem ist, that the height can't be calculated as the DOM hasn't been updated when the open-click occurs.

How could I solve this? Thank you for your support!

(The collabse is animated via css transition height, therefore I have to calc the height of the element as the content is dynamic in height)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import "./Collabsable.css";
import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

class Collabsable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if (props.open) {
            this.state = {
                isExpanded: true,
                inTransition: false,
                hasBeenOpened: true
            };
        } else {
            this.state = {
                isExpanded: false,
                inTransition: false,
                hasBeenOpened: false
            };
        }
    }

    handleClickToggle(event) {
        this.setState({
            isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded,
            height: this.refs.innerContainer.clientHeight,
            hasBeenOpened: true
        });
    }

    handleTransitionEnd(event) {
        if (this.state.isExpanded) {
            this.setState({ inTransition: false });
        } else {
            this.setState({ inTransition: true });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {headerTitle, headerAdditionalButtons} = this.props;
        const {isExpanded, height} = this.state;
        const currentHeight = isExpanded ? height : 0;

        let children = this.props.lazyChildrenRender &&
            !this.state.hasBeenOpened &&
            !this.state.isExpanded &&
            !this.state.inTransition ? null : this.props.children;

        return (
            <div className={`collabsable ${isExpanded ? 'is-expanded': ''}`}>
                <div className={"collabsable_header"}>
                    <div className="collabsable_header_title">{headerTitle}</div>
                    <div className="collabsable_header_buttons">
                        <div className="collabsable_header_buttons_additional">{headerAdditionalButtons}</div>
                        <div className="collabsable_header_buttons_toggle">
                            <button onClick={(event) => this.handleClickToggle(event)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="angle-down" /></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="collabsable_container" style={{height: currentHeight+'px'}} onTransitionEnd={(event) => this.handleTransitionEnd(event)}>
                    <div className="collabsable_container_inner" ref="innerContainer">
                        {children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Collabsable.propTypes = {
    headerTitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    headerAdditionalButtons: PropTypes.object,
    lazyChildrenRender: PropTypes.bool,
    hasBeenOpened: PropTypes.bool,
    open: PropTypes.bool
};

Collabsable.defaultProps = {
    headerTitle: "Collabsable Component Headline",
    headerAdditionalButtons: null,
    lazyChildrenRender: false,
    hasBeenOpened: false,
    open: false
};

export default Collabsable;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are facing 2 issues here, you need to know the number of elements that will be loaded and how to lazy load the data/child of each elements of your collapsible component right ?